# A question on a class of sawtooth functions

Tags: real-analysis

On $[-1,1]$ define $h(x) = |x|$. If extended to $\mathbb R$ by requiring that $h(2+x) = h(x)$ then this is a sawtooth function. I am interested in $h_n (x) = (1/2^n) h(2^n x)$. Please can you tell me if my thoughts are correct:

On $[0,1]$ for all $n$: $h_n(x) = h(x)$.

On $[1,2]$: $h_n (x) = -x + {1\over 2^{n-1}}$. For example $h_1 = (1/2)h(2x) = -x + 1$. The functions $h_n$ therefore jump at $1$ from $1$ to $-(1-{1\over 2^{n}})$ and again at $2$ from $-2 + {1\over 2^{n}})$ to $0$.

The limit of $h_n$ as $n \to \infty$ is
$$ H(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x & x \in [0,1]\\
-x & x \in [1,2]
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Do you want $h(x+2) = h(x)$ and $h_n(x) = (1/2^n) h(2^nx)$?

Comment: @John yes, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$h_2(1/2) = (1/2^2)h(2^2/2) = h(2)/4 = h(0)/4 = 0$

but

$h(1/2) = 1/2$

so the first claim is not true.

The functions $h_1$, $h_2$, ... are also sawtooth functions, just scaled down: in the terminology of waves, $h_0$ ($=h$) has "wavelength" $2$ and "amplitude" $1$, while $h_n$ has wavelength $2^{1-n}$ and amplitude $2^{-n}$.

So $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} h_n(x) = 0$ for all $x$: to prove this formally, note that $|h(x)| \leq 1$ for all $x$, and so $|h_n(x)| \leq 2^{-n}$ for all $x$.